# ASP.NET Development Server not cleaning up values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, garbage-collection

I have a string which I declare as "" at the start of a method. I've set up breakpoints each time the string is used. The first time I debug the app, it rightly stops at where I declared the variable. Then I stop debugging, try debug again, and it doesn't stop where the variable is declared - it stops at where I am supposed to be giving it a value for the first time (except it already has a value according to VS debugger!!). It's not just when I debug, it's when I run the app normally too. Restarting ASP.NET Development Server fixes the problem. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Show how you declaring variable

Comment: public static string subsection = "";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about static members [Static Classes and Static Class Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). I think you declared static field at global.asax file or somewhere similar. Because of it field is initialzed only once at appliaction start. When you start/stop/start debugging of application, you not restart application. Application restart occurs when you restart ASP.NET Development Server.